# Getting out from Cygwin path in C

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm new in programming. I just want to get out the Cygdrive to be able to execute commands outside `/cygdrive/c`.

My code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    if(remove("test.txt") == 0){

        printf("Removed succesfully.");
    }

    return 0;
```

And I get the file removed, but just inside my Proyect folder.
What I need is to get 'test.txt' file deleted in any of the paths I want.

Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    chdir("C:\\\\Windows\\\\system32");

    if(remove("test.txt") == 0){

        printf("Removed succesfully.");
    }

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing from cygwin to MinGW solved the problem.